# What's a valid use case for the 300 HTTP status code?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I've never had to use a 300 status code, but I assume it's important (200 & 400 come up all the time).

I know that it stands for 'Multiple Choices' and that you return a list of resources:

```
The requested resource corresponds to any one of a set of representations, 
each with its own specific location, and agent- driven negotiation information
(section 12) is being provided so that the user (or user agent) can select 
a preferred representation and redirect its request to that location.

Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity containing 
a list of resource characteristics and location(s) from which the user or 
user agent can choose the one most appropriate.
```

But I don't see when I would ever use this.

NB. this isn't a question about 301 permanent / 302 temporary redirects, but about the 300.

Comment: `It, for instance, could be used to present different format options for video, list files with different extensions, or word sense disambiguation.` Taken from wiki.

Comment: My reading of it is that it's for situations where the user has specified a resource for which there is more than one possible way of viewing it (a text document in multiple languages, an image in multiple formats and/or sizes, etc).  For example if you have an english and german version of the same document with urls /doc-en.html and doc-de.html, you could have any requests to /doc.html respond with HTTP300 and a list of the en and de versions.